# How to add a new channel with overrides in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need to create a channel with overrides (can't view, can't send) apart from the person who sent the message himself.

My current code:

```
if (command === "help") {
  if (!args.length) return message.reply("Try again with a reason.")
    message.guild.channels.create(message.author.id, "text")
      .updateOverwrite(message.guild.roles.everyone, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false })
      .updateOverwrite(message.author, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true })
      .send(`SUPPORT\n${message.author} has a question.`)
    message.channel.send("Your wish is my command.");
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍ Hi bro.

- use `!args` instead of `!args.length` ( line:2 )
- replace this lines ( 3, 4, 5 ) with this code to create a channel :

  ```
  // Create a new channel with permission overwrites
  message.guild.channels.create(message.author.id, {
    type: 'text',
    permissionOverwrites: [{
      id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    }]
  }).then(channel => {
    channel.updateOverwrite(message.author.id, {
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true
    })
  })
  ```

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how to delete a channel?

Comment: @LyamDexterMosnier , to delete a Discord channel you can use. . . `message.guild.channels.cache.get("channel_id").delete()`